# Upload image to file and information to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

This is my form

```
<h3>Add Image</h3>
<form action="datauploadprocess.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post">
Subject: <input name="subject" type="text" id="subject"  /><br />
Content: <input name="content" type="text" id="content"  /><br />
Image Name: <input name="imageName" type="text" id="imageName" /><br />

Upload Image (jpg only):
<label>
    <input type="file" name="fileField" id="fileField" />
</label>
<label>
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Add Photo" />
</label>
</form>
```

and my process...

```
<?php include "header.php";?>
<?php
//Parser for Add Photo Form
if (isset($_POST["subject"], $_POST["content"], $_POST["imageName"])){
$subject = mysqli_real_escape_string ($con, isset ($_POST["subject"]));
$content = mysqli_real_escape_string ($con, isset ($_POST["content"]));
$imageName = mysqli_real_escape_string ($con, isset ($_POST["imageName"]));

//add photo to db
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "
           INSERT INTO
            Blog (
            subject,
            content,
            imageName
           )VALUES(
            '$subject',
            '$content',
            '$imageName')")
            or die(mysqli_error($con));
$pid = mysqli_insert_id();
$newname = "$pid.jpg";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'],"blogPhotos/$newname");
header("location: datauploadprocess.php");
exit();
}
?>
 <?php include"footer.php"?>
```

It runs with no errors but in the database the values for subject, content and image name show as '1' every time.  Also the image doesn't appear to be adding to the folder.
My connection is included in the
    
in the correct format.

Edited 15:45
subject, content and image name problem is now solved but the image still doesn't upload to the specified file.
New process code;

```
//Parser for Add Photo Form
if (isset($_POST["subject"], $_POST["content"], $_POST["imageName"])){
$subject = mysqli_real_escape_string ($con, ($_POST["subject"]));
$content = mysqli_real_escape_string ($con, ($_POST["content"]));
$imageName = mysqli_real_escape_string ($con, ($_POST["imageName"]));
```

Update...
I was missing the connection information for the line

```
$pid = mysqli_insert_id();
```

It should be

```
$pid = mysqli_insert_id($con);
```

All working now.

Comment: Have you tried to print the var before doing the query to see how the values are?

Comment: The `1`'s are by design as you're using `isset ($_POST["subject"])` instead of just `$_POST["subject"]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be, Remove `isset()` function and its result is boolean

```
$subject = mysqli_real_escape_string ($con, $_POST["subject"]);
$content = mysqli_real_escape_string ($con, $_POST["content"]);
$imageName = mysqli_real_escape_string ($con, $_POST["imageName"]);
```

Comment: A little addon: to check if post field is not empty use operator `?:` : `$subject = mysqli_real_escape_string ($con, isset($_POST["subject"])?$_POST["subject"]:'')`

Comment: This solved the problem of it uploading values '1' to the database, thanks! It still won't upload the photo, any ideas on that?

Comment: Upload path is correct and the file permissions shouldn't affect it.

Comment: `print_r($_FILES['fileField'])` to check all the file parameters are present

Comment: Managed to upload images.  I don't know what was wrong but it works now.

Answer (score 1):

```
$subject = mysqli_real_escape_string ($con, isset ($_POST["subject"]));
```

The isset() in this line will return true/false. It is returning true which is then interpreted as a 1.

Remove the isset() from inside your escape functions, you want to escape the values, not the result of the isset()